# How to get this desired array of object from the input array of object ? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my input array of object, I have a field called Grade and I have field called Thickness. If in a particular object, if Grade and Thickness are same, their Qty should be added. Grade AU27 and Thickness 5.00 has two quantities (2.00 and 17.00). So we have create a field Thickness5Qty should value (2.00 and 17.00)

Similarly for Grade FE500D, there are 3 types of thickness, so Thickness10, Thickness12 and Thickness8 fields are created.

​ ​

```
 var input = [
 {
  "Qty": "2.00",
  "Grade": "AU27",
  "Thickness": "5.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "7.00",
  "Grade": "AU27",
  "Thickness": "10.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "17.00",
  "Grade": "AU27",
  "Thickness": "5.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "51.00",
  "Grade": "FE500D",
  "Thickness": "10.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "69.00",
  "Grade": "FE500D",
  "Thickness": "12.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "30.00",
  "Grade": "FE500D",
  "Thickness": "8.00",
 },
 {
  "Qty": "92.00",
  "Grade": "FE500D",
  "Thickness": "10.00",
  }
];
```

My desired result

```
 var output = [
  {
    "Grade": "AU27",
"Thickness5Qty": "19.00",// sum of all Grade - AU27 Quantities where Thickness is 5 (1st and 3rd objects quantities merged)
"Thickness10Qty": "7.00",
  },
  {
   "Grade": "FE500D",
   "Thickness10": "143.00",//sum of Grade-FE500D where Thickness is 10
"Thickness12": "69.00",
"Thickness8": "30.00"
   }
 ];
```

How can I get the output array of object from the input array of object?

**Updated Question - New field needed total Quantity**

**My desired result**

```
 var output = [
  {
    "Grade": "AU27",
"Thickness5Qty": "19.00",// sum of all Grade - AU27 Quantities where Thickness is 5 (1st and 3rd objects quantities merged)
"Thickness10Qty": "7.00",
"TotalQty": "26.00"
  },
  {
   "Grade": "FE500D",
   "Thickness10Qty": "143.00",//sum of Grade-FE500D where Thickness is 10
"Thickness12Qty": "69.00",
"Thickness8Qty": "30.00",
"TotalQty": "242.00"
   }
 ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to create a key value paired grouped object and extract grouped object values using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method.

```js
var input = [{"Qty":"2.00","Grade":"AU27","Thickness":"5.00"},{"Qty":"7.00","Grade":"AU27","Thickness":"10.00"},{"Qty":"17.00","Grade":"AU27","Thickness":"5.00"},{"Qty":"51.00","Grade":"FE500D","Thickness":"10.00"},{"Qty":"69.00","Grade":"FE500D","Thickness":"12.00"},{"Qty":"30.00","Grade":"FE500D","Thickness":"8.00"},{"Qty":"92.00","Grade":"FE500D","Thickness":"10.00"}];

          // extract values from object
let res = Object.values(input.reduce((obj, { Grade, Thickness, Qty }) => { // extract all values
  // convert thickness to number
  Thickness = +Thickness;
  // key for sum
  let key = `Thickness${Thickness}Qty`;
  // define object correspoding to grade if not defined
  obj[Grade] = obj[Grade] || { Grade , TotalQty : 0 };      
  // define sum correspoding to grade key if not defined
  obj[Grade][key] = obj[Grade][key] || 0;
  // add to existing sum
  obj[Grade][key] += +Qty; // if you want sum with two fractional points then obj[Grade][key] = (+obj[Grade][key] + +Qty).toFixed(2)
  // add with total
  obj[Grade].TotalQty += +Qty;  
  // return object reference   
  return obj;
// set initial value as empty object
}, {}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Scooby :  what's the difference ?

Comment: Now the answer is OK. Will it work for any number of Grades and Thickness?

Comment: @Scooby : yes it will

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, can you kindly check my updated question, I want a new field called TotalQty which is summation of all available ThicknessQty

Comment: Thanks a lot. I upvoted you and marked your answer as correct

Comment: I want the total quantity in two decimal places. One last help. Please reply

Comment: @Scooby : `if you want sum with two fractional points then obj[Grade][key] = (+obj[Grade][key] + +Qty).toFixed(2)`

Comment: That is OK. The Thickness5Qty,Thickness10Qty are coming in two decimal places, but the TotalQty is coming as integer only

Comment: Check this JSbin -  - https://jsbin.com/qejepexoti/edit?js,console   TotalQty is coming as integer, not as decimal upto 2 places

Comment: @Scooby : `obj[Grade].TotalQty =(+obj[Grade].TotalQty +  +Qty).toFixed(2);`

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You helped me a lot